# Which AWS services to use for processing 20TB of Parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing

I have 20 Terabytes of data (collection of parquet files) sitting on an s3 bucket. I have a quite straightforward custom algorithm (pandas + numpy + scikit-learn) which I would like to apply on the aforementioned dataset. The data can be split into roughly 600 chunks (approx 30 GBs each) and my algorithm can run on those chunks independently. The algorithm takes around 2 hours to run on each chunk. I would like to leverage AWS services to perform the below steps:

1. Split 20 TB of data in 600 chunks based on a particular column's value
2. Spin up multiple (maybe 600?) machines and send one chunk to one machine at a time
3. Execute my algorithm on each of the machines in parallel

Which AWS services should I use at each stage? How do I integrate those services? Can anyone list them out in details?

Ideally I would like my algorithm to run no more than 24 hours.

Comment: For steps 2. and 3. Fargate seems as great option. You can very easily scale it up and down even for that many of machines. You have to just ask AWS to increase limit for Fargate machines (default is 50 I think)

Comment: This is exactly what EMR is intended for.

Comment: @libik That's also likely to be the most expensive option... by a lot

Comment: Thank you both! @jordanm: Can you point me to some good documentation/tutorial on EMR? I am going to use distributed computing for the first time. (sweating)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the exact use-case for running [Apache Spark on Amazon EMR - Big Data Platform - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/features/spark/). It is designed to provide massively parallel processing on data stored in Amazon S3.

Also, it should be able to process data files in parallel without you having to split them.

I would recommend watching: [AWS re:Invent 2019: Deep dive into running Apache Spark on Amazon EMR (ANT308-R1) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIwJlfEAlHQ&feature=youtu.be)